# SQL query not returning rows during update of different records

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, isolation-level

Background:
I have two programs that are performing a kind of replication operation, they read data from two different systems (One checks a separate SQL Server, one fetches data from a External REST API) and they bring the results into a single table on our system. The data sets and records are tiny and these programs loop 20 and 60 seconds. 
The data is requested using datetimestamp logic (e.g. last 3 days) and then we check if we have processed these requests before using a unique reference which is in our table. 
Before we insert this new data we query to see if the reference exists, if so ignore if not insert the record.
These two programs do their jobs well.

We then have a user C# win forms program that deals with this data and one operation runs SQL transaction from the program rather than a stored procedure. One of the tasks is to update a status flag in the above table.

The issue is that intermittently we seem to process a duplicate reference number, meaning the programs above when doing a SELECT on the table don't pick up the reference.

We have isolated that this only happens when we run the procedure from the program and that the duplicates records are unrelated to the updating dataset. Meaning the data that is being updated is not related in terms of business logic (not the same records).

The isolation level would be the default C# chooses for a transaction.

The question:
1) While the transaction is updating the status records (which it will lock) why would we lose unrelated records in the same table when doing a read?

Comment: Is it possible due to the following code:  dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT reference FROM TableView WHERE RefCol=@RefReceviedC2D AND MsgType=@SRCType"
 SqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
if(dbReader.HasRows)
{ //Already Processed Record code}                    
else
{ //Insert new record code}

Comment: If we are unpdating the same table, would the HasRows flag still be false even if the record existed but there was a timeout?

Comment: I have read that SqlDataReader.HasRows can return false even if ther are rows. Well if that true its detrimental to my logic.

Comment: I have been able to replicate and debug the session. And the datareders.Hasrows is false, but in visual studio if I look at the datareadr object while the other proces is running I see a deadlock message:Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. So the question is why is this exception not thrown? rather the program things the row does not exist.

Comment: I have mittigated by adding a table went on the duplicate checking programs to use readuncommitted hint.

Comment: It helps to get good answers if SSCCE[http://sscce.org/] is provided